# Dynamic Parameterized query with dapper

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, dapper

I want to write a query with a dynamic list of parameters (depending on parameter is set or not).
I want to execute the query on an oracle database using dapper.

Sample code:

```
        var sqlParams = new List<object>();
        var sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.Append("SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE 1 = 1 ");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aParam))
        {
            sqlBuilder.Append(" AND A LIKE ?");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bParam))
        {
            sqlBuilder.Append(" AND B LIKE ? ");
        }

        var sql = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        return this.Connection.Query<Equipment>(
            sql,
            new { aParam, bParam }   // ??
            ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper only really works with named parameters. I seem to recall that in oracle they are colon-prefixed, so:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aParam))
{
    sqlBuilder.Append(" AND A LIKE :aParam");
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bParam))
{
    sqlBuilder.Append(" AND B LIKE :bParam");
}
```

Now your existing code here:

```
return this.Connection.Query<Equipment>(
    sql,
    new { aParam, bParam }
    ).ToList();
```

should work. Dapper uses the names of the members of the anonymous type as parameter names. It additionally includes some very basic code to check whether any given member does not exist in the sql, so if your sql *only* mentions `:bParam`, it won't actually add the `aParam` value as a parameter.

In more complicated scenarios, there is also a `DynamicParameters` object you can use, that functions more like a dictionary - but you don't need that here.

Comment: How would you add `aParam, bParam` dynamically in the second snippet? Is it possible to replace `new { aParam, bParam }` with an `ExpandoObject`? I don't want to hard-code `aParam, bParam`. I want to add them via a loop. It seems like `Query<Equipment>()` does not support an ExpandoObject as its second argument though.

Comment: @kkuilla you can use `DynamicParameters`, or frankly you can just pass both in (dapper will ignore any that *obviously* aren't used)